# Couldn't export excel file through asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this code to export GridView data to excel, code is working fine but Excel file is not supporting some operations; If I'm printing labels from this File it is showing "Error: External table is not in expected format"
What to do???
Is there any way to export Excel in simply or without any formatting as the excel has same formatting as of GridView...

```
protected void btnExcel1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "ExcelSheet.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    //Change the Header Row back to white color
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    //Applying stlye to gridview header cells
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1");
    }
    int j = 1;
    //This loop is used to apply stlye to cells based on particular row
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        gvrow.BackColor = Color.White;
        if (j <= GridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code :-

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

        //Print using Ofice InterOp
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

        var workbook = (Excel._Workbook)(excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));

        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.Tables.Count; i++)
        {

                if (workbook.Sheets.Count <= i)
                {
                    workbook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                        Type.Missing);
                }

                //NOTE: Excel numbering goes from 1 to n
                var currentSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[i + 1]; 

                for (var y = 0; y < dataset.Tables[i].Rows.Count; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x < dataset.Tables[i].Rows[y].ItemArray.Count(); x++)
                    {
                        currentSheet.Cells[y+1, x+1] = dataset.Tables[i].Rows[y].ItemArray[x];
                    }
                }
        }

        string outfile = @"C:\excel.xlsx";

        workbook.SaveAs( outfile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing);

        workbook.Close();
        excel.Quit();
```